# IFRAME:hover in IE and Edge doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, microsoft-edge

In IE and Edge it works only when you hover over the border and not the contents of `IFRAME`

On Chrome, Safari whatever it works as expected (`:hover` stays when hovering over border AND content)

https://jsfiddle.net/zy7tqvxf/1/

Is there any workaround for this without adding extra elements and javascript handlers?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that IE thinks the iframe is not part of the HTML and so `:hover` isn't registered. I found a fix using javascript, and adding a `hover` class, [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4a8otfLd/).

```
$('#frame').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$('#frame').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: sure it will help, I wanted to find a way without js, but looks like it isn't possible